# SQL Developer: Difference between PLSCOPE_SETTINGS 'None' and 'All'?

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I tried to create a ddl script with some triggers. Its for a university submission, so multiple users share the DB and get their own schemes.

However with *Tools->Preferences ->Database->PL/SQL Compiler -> PLScope identifiers: "All"* the proccess always crashed, while setting it to *None* it got created just fine.

What exacty is the difference between those two settings?

Comment: Could you please paste the code which is failing and after error message you are getting.

Answer (score 0):

[PL/Scope](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28424/adfns_plscope.htm#g1010526) is

> a compiler-driven tool that collects data about identifiers in PL/SQL source code at program-unit compilation time and makes it available in static data dictionary views. The collected data includes information about identifier types, usages (declaration, definition, reference, call, assigment) and the location of each usage in the source code.

Here are [identifiers](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28320/statviews_1089.htm#REFRN20599); you can query `all_identifiers` or `user_identifiers`; DBA has `dba_identifiers` on disposal. It

> displays information about the identifiers in the stored objects accessible to the current user.

Why it fails when set to "All"? No idea. Try to query `all_identifiers` and compare the list with the one in documentation, see what they do. Maybe you'll find something useful.

Comment: I cant really spot a difference between those. Interestingly I create three other triggers that don't cause a crash on either setting^^ But thanks of course :)

Comment: Seems like you need to look at the failing trigger and figure out what's different about **it** compared to the successful triggers.

Comment: The difference is the db collects additional metadata on your code..when you say it crashes, we really need to see the actual errors.